# Validation rule that flags if File is not present on custom object?

Tags: custom-object, validation, files

Requirement is to prevent saving of a record if a File (in this case, a quote) is not attached.

Is this accomplishable declaratively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general reading of the question? It's not possible at all. You can't attach a file to a record prior to its being saved, because there's no record for the file to be attached to.

But suppose that what you mean is that you want to require a File to be attached *prior to making some other change* to the record - like moving an Opportunity to Closed Won stage, for example.

That is possible in theory, but the complexities associated with the Content system and the restrictions on querying Content add enough roadblocks that I don't think there's a purely declarative route.

Files are represented as a `ContentDocument` record, whose children `ContentVersion` records store the various versions of the file (there may only be one). A junction object, `ContentDocumentLink`, connects the Document to the many locations in which it may appear or be shared.

I haven't tried creating a Content rollup with [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries). There is an [open issue](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/issues/433) filed on that project suggesting that it may be problematic. Since `ContentDocumentLink` isn't supported by Process Builder, I think an application like DLRS is the only route to providing a declarative solution. That really just leaves custom code, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I created a rollup with DLRS using the ContentDocumentLink object as David Reed recommended above, and it worked perfectly. I then was able to create a normal validation rule requiring the rollup was greater than 0.